# How to map java's AffineTransform to android's Matrix?

Tags: java, android

Suppose I initialize an AffineTransform as below:

AffineTransform af = new AffineTransform(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

How would I create an equivalent Matrix using android's sdk?

Comment: need to apply setPivotX(0); setPivotY(0); to get exact position after rotation why is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [AffineTransform's javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html):

```
[ x']   [  m00  m01  m02  ] [ x ]   [ m00x + m01y + m02 ]
[ y'] = [  m10  m11  m12  ] [ y ] = [ m10x + m11y + m12 ]
[ 1 ]   [   0    0    1   ] [ 1 ]   [         1         ]
```

Not sure, but perhaps

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setValues(new float[]{2,3,4,5,6,7,0,0,1});
```

EDIT:
Commenter points out that the order should be

```
m.setValues(new float[]{2,4,6,3,5,7,0,0,1});
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that in the doc.  It is actually:

Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setValues(new float[]{2,4,6,3,5,7,0,0,1});

Comment: Really?  That's bizarre.  I would think it would be either column order or row order.. what you posted seems to be a mix

Comment: its because the constructor for AffineTransform is in a weird order:
AffineTransform(float m00, float m10, float m01, float m11, float m02, float m12)

Comment: The matrix is transposed, that's why.

Comment: need to apply setPivotX(0); setPivotY(0); to get exact position after rotation why is that?

Answer (score 6):

The order provided in AffineTransform is provided as:

> `java.awt.geom.AffineTransform.AffineTransform(float m00, float m10, float m01, float m11, float m02, float m12)`
>
> Constructs a new AffineTransform from 6 floating point values representing the 6 specifiable entries of the 3x3 transformation matrix.
>
> Parameters:
>   **m00** the X coordinate scaling element of the 3x3 matrix
>   **m10** the Y coordinate shearing element of the 3x3 matrix
>   **m01** the X coordinate shearing element of the 3x3 matrix
>   **m11** the Y coordinate scaling element of the 3x3 matrix
>   **m02** the X coordinate translation element of the 3x3 matrix
>   **m12** the Y coordinate translation element of the 3x3 matrix

An example implementation:

```
new AffineTransform(
    q0, q1, q2,
    q3, q4, q5);
```

counter-intuitively yields:

```
[  m00  m01  m02  ]   [ q0  q2  q4 ]
[  m10  m11  m12  ] = [ q1  q3  q5 ]
[   0    0    1   ]   [  0   0   1 ]
```

To accomplish the same result with `android.graphics.Matrix`:

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setValues(new float[] {
    q0, q2, q4,
    q1, q3, q5,
     0,  0,  1
}
```

I think Matrix's `setValues()` method documentation could be improved; it should reflect that the order of its parameters is:

> `void android.graphics.Matrix.setValues(float[] values)`
>
> Copy 9 values from the array into the matrix. Depending on the implementation of Matrix, these may be transformed into 16.16 integers in the Matrix, such that a subsequent call to getValues() will not yield exactly the same values.
>
> The values are provided into the 3x3 matrix in the following order:
>
> ```
> float[] {  
>     m00, m01, m02,
>     m10, m11, m12,
>     m20, m21, m22
> }
> ```
>
> Where:
>
> **m00** the X coordinate scaling element of the 3x3 matrix (`Matrix.MSCALE_X`)
>   **m01** the X coordinate shearing element of the 3x3 matrix (`Matrix.MSKEW_X`)
>   **m02** the X coordinate translation element of the 3x3 matrix (`Matrix.MTRANS_X`)
>   **m10** the Y coordinate shearing element of the 3x3 matrix (`Matrix.MSKEW_Y`)
>   **m11** the Y coordinate scaling element of the 3x3 matrix (`Matrix.MSCALE_Y`)
>   **m12** the Y coordinate translation element of the 3x3 matrix (`Matrix.MTRANS_Y`)
>   **m20** the first perspective element of the 3x3 matrix (`Matrix.MPERSP_0`)
>   **m21** the second perspective element of the 3x3 matrix (`Matrix.MPERSP_1`)
>   **m22** the third perspective element of the 3x3 matrix (`Matrix.MPERSP_2`)

Comment: i am taking matrix from image using getmatrix . which order should i follow ?

Comment: Android uses the same order for matrices throughout, so you won't ever see the AWT order in the SDK.

Comment: -ve was a mistake from my side, the order of matrix was different. but still i need to apply setPivotX(0); setPivotY(0); to get exact position after rotation why is that

Answer (score 0):

This is a demo Java code:

```
 public static float[] createMatrixValues(AffineTransform Tx) {
    double[] at = new double[9];
    Tx.getMatrix(at);
    float[] f = new float[at.length];
    f[0] = (float) at[0];
    f[1] = (float) at[2];
    f[2] = (float) at[4];
    f[3] = (float) at[1];
    f[4] = (float) at[3];
    f[5] = (float) at[5];
    f[6] = 0;
    f[7] = 0;
    f[8] = 1;
    return f;
}
```

and to create the Matrix object:

```
public static Matrix createMatrixObj(AffineTransform Tx) {
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.reset();
    m.setValues(createMatrix(Tx));
    return m;
}
```

I hope this helper methods solves your question.

Comment: need to apply setPivotX(0); setPivotY(0); to get exact position after rotation why is that?