# Android: Getting a Rotated OSM Map to Fill the Entire Screen

Tags: android, layout, openstreetmap

I'm working on an application that uses the OpenStreetMap (OSM) API to display various points of interest on an offline map, composed of static tiles.

One of the features that I am currently implementing is having the map rotate in accordance with the bearing determined by the phone (via GPS). I was able to implement the actual rotation without too much effort, but since my code rotates the entire canvas -- perhaps a rather naive approach -- I now have blank corners on the screen where no new tiles are being loaded to compensate for the fact that the rotated tiles no longer fill these pixels.

After a bit of Googling, I found a few suggestions as to how I might be able to solve this issue, but so far no luck.

In one of [Mr. Romain Guy's posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012129/how-to-rotate-mapview/5039474#5039474), he mentions the following:

> I have done this in the past and it requires to create a custom
>   ViewGroup that rotates the Canvas in the dispatchDraw() method. You
>   also need to increase the size of the MapView (so that it draws enough
>   pixels when rotated.) You will also need to rotate the touch events in
>   dispatchTouchEvent(). Or if you use Android 3.0 you can simply call
>   theMapView.rotate()

Taking his advice on map rotation, I have implemented dispatchDraw() and dispatchTouchEvent() as suggested, but I'm having trouble with the part where he mentions that I need to increase the size of the MapView?

Is this something that I do in the XML file, like suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813049/how-to-create-a-view-that-is-bigger-than-the-screen)?

Or, can I somehow override the onMeasure() function in my subclassed RelativeLayout class that handles my map rotation?

Suggestions and hints are most welcome.

**UPDATE:**

In an attempt to find an acceptable solution to this problem, I tried to change the size of the canvas. The thinking was that with a canvas size that is bigger than the actual screen size, I might be able to move the blank corners off the screen entirely. Unfortunately, there does not appear to be an actual canvas.size() option; the best I found was canvas.scale().

Using canvas.scale(), I was able to increase the scale of the canvas by a factor of 2 in both the horizontal as well as vertical dimensions. This means, however, that the image is effectively zoomed in, causing unacceptable pixelation to the map tiles.

Does anyone know where the size of the canvas gets declared, and if changing the size of the canvas might actually solve my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up following Romain Guy's advice (the same advice that I posted in my question). That is, I created my own custom `ViewGroup` by extending the `RelativeLayout`, and I then increased the size of my `mapView` to provide coverage of the entire screen. Extending the `RelativeLayout ViewGroup` was necessary so that I could override the `dispatchDraw(...)`, the `onMeasure(...)`, as well as the `dispatchTouchEvent(...)` functions to enable the desired map rotation features for my application.

The `dispatchDraw(...)` function essentially intercepts calls to the `onDraw(...)` function, performs a few specific manipulations on the input to that function and then releases it to be processed. In our case, we'll want to rotate the `mapView` canvas before it makes its way to the actual `onDraw(...)` function. This is why we'll need to override this function.

Specifically, the `dispatchDraw(...)` function takes as input a canvas object, which (in this case) represents the OSM `mapView` object (as defined in the XML file below). If a rotation is to be applied to the canvas, we'll want to locate the center of the map, translate (i.e. move) the map so that the center of the map sits on the origin of the coordinate system, rotated the map about the origin of the coordinate system, and then, finally, we'll want to dispatch this modified canvas to the next stage in the rendering pipeline.

My code for this is below; note that `Manager` is my own singleton creation that won't exist in your implementation unless you write one yourself!

```
    /**
 * @param pCanvas
 * @return void
 * 
 * This function intercepts all dispatches to the onDraw function of the 
 * super, and it rotates the canvas in accordance with the user's wishes
 * using the phone bearing as determined either through the magnetometer
 * or GPS fixes.
 */
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(final Canvas pCanvas) {
    final long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // If automatic map rotation has been enabled, get bearing from phone:
    if (Manager.getInstance().getMapRotationMode() != Constants.DISABLED) {
        mBearing = Manager.getInstance().getPhoneBearing();

        // Save the state of the transformation matrix:
        pCanvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);

        // getWidth() and getHeight() return the size of the canvas as 
        // defined in the XML file, and not the size of the screen!
        int canvasOffsetX = -(getWidth() / 2) + (screenWidth / 2);
        int canvasOffsetY = -(getHeight() / 2) + (screenHeight / 2);

        // Set origin of canvas to center of map:
        pCanvas.translate(canvasOffsetX, canvasOffsetY); 

        // Rotate the canvas to the correct bearing:
        pCanvas.rotate(-mBearing, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);

        // Pass on the rotated canvas, and restore after that:
        super.dispatchDraw(pCanvas);

        // Balance out the call to save, and restore the matrix to 
        // saved state:
        pCanvas.restore();          
    } // end if

    else { // If map rotation has not been enabled:
        super.dispatchDraw(pCanvas);
    } // end else

    final long endMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (LOG_ENABLED) {
        Log.i(TAG, "mapView Dispatch Time: " + (endMs - startMs) + "ms");
    } // end if
} // end dispatchDraw()
```

Next we'll need to override `dispatchTouchEvent(...)`, because any rotation of the OSM `mapView` canvas ends up rotating not only the graphical representation of the map, but also everything else related to that Activity (this occurs as a side effect of my specific implementation); that is, touch event coordinates remain relative to the `mapView` canvas after being rotated and not relative to the actual phone. For example, if we imagine the canvas being rotated by 180 degrees, then if the user attempts to pan the map to the left, it will instead move to the map to the right, since everything is upside-down!

In code, you might correct for this problem as follows:

```
/**
 * @param event
 * @return boolean
 * 
 * This function intercepts all interactions with the touch display (that is, 
 * all touchEvents), and for each finger on the screen, or pointer, the
 * function applies the necessary rotation to counter the rotation of the 
 * map. The coordinate of each pointer is also modified so that it returns
 * the correct location on the enlarged canvas. This was necessary to return
 * the correct coordinate for actions such as double-tap, and proper icon 
 * identification upon clicking an icon.
 */
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Get the number of pointers (i.e. fingers on screen) from the passed
    // in MotionEvent:
    float degrees = Manager.getInstance().getPhoneBearing();
    int numPointers = event.getPointerCount();
    int[] pointerIDs = new int[numPointers];
    PointerCoords[] pointerCoords = new PointerCoords[numPointers];

    // Extract all pointers from the touch event:
    for (int i = 0; i < numPointers; i++) {
        pointerIDs[i] = event.getPointerId(i);
        pointerCoords[i] = new PointerCoords();

        event.getPointerCoords(i, pointerCoords[i]);
    } // end for

    // Correct each pointer coordinate set for map rotation:
    for (int i = 0; i < numPointers; i++) {
        // x and y end up representing points on the canvas, although they
        // are derived from points on the screen:
        float x = pointerCoords[i].x;
        float y = pointerCoords[i].y;

        // Get the center of the MapView:
        int centerX = getWidth() / 2;
        int centerY = getHeight() / 2;

        // Convert to radians
        float rad = (float) ((degrees * Math.PI) / 180f);
        float s = (float) Math.sin(rad);
        float c = (float) Math.cos(rad);

        // Translate point to origin:
        x -= centerX;
        y -= centerY;

        // Apply rotation
        float tmpX = x * c - y * s;
        float tmpY = x * s + y * c;
        x = tmpX;
        y = tmpY;           

        // Offset the coordinates to compensate for the fact that the
        // canvas is 1200 by 1200, the phone screen is smaller, and
        // they don't overlap nicely:
        x += (600 - (screenWidth / 2)) * c - (600 - (screenHeight / 2)) * s;
        y += (600 - (screenWidth / 2)) * s + (600 - (screenHeight / 2)) * c;

        // Translate point back:
        x += centerX;
        y += centerY;

        pointerCoords[i].x = x;
        pointerCoords[i].y = y;

        // Catlog:
        if (LOG_ENABLED) Log.i(TAG, "(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
    } // end for

    // Create new event to pass along the modified pointers.
    // Need API level 9 or higher to make this work!
    MotionEvent newEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event.getDownTime(), event
            .getEventTime(), event.getAction(), event.getPointerCount(),
            pointerIDs, pointerCoords, event.getMetaState(), event
                    .getXPrecision(), event.getYPrecision(), event
                    .getDeviceId(), event.getEdgeFlags(),
            event.getSource(), event.getFlags());

    // Dispatch the newly modified touch event:
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(newEvent);
} // end dispatchTouchEvent()
```

Finally, the trick to getting the corresponding XML for the map activity to work properly is to utilize a `FrameLayout` as the parent to all other GUI elements in my layout. This allowed me to make the `mapView` dimensions considerably larger than the dimensions of the display on my Nexus One (480 by 800). This solution also allowed me to nest a `RelativeLayout` inside my `FrameLayout` while still respecting the device's actual display dimensions when using `match_parent` and similar parameters.

The relevant portion of my XML layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--Note that the layout width and height is defined in px and not dip!-->

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/MapViewLayout">

<a.relevant.path.RotatingRelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="1200px"
    android:layout_height="1200px">

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="1200px" 
        android:layout_height="1200px"
        android:enabled="true"      
        android:clickable="true"/>          
</a.relevant.path.RotatingRelativeLayout>   

<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftSlideHandleButton" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#D0000000">

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/mapZoomOutButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/zoom_out_button"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:onClick="zoomOutButton"/>

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/mapZoomInButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/zoom_in_button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="zoomInButton"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/headerSpeedText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#33B5E5"
            android:text="Speed: "
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mapZoomOutButton"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/headerSpeedReading"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#33B5E5"
            android:text="N/A"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="27dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/headerSpeedText"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/headerBearingText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#33B5E5"
            android:text="Bearing: "
            android:paddingLeft="15dip"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mapZoomOutButton"
            android:layout_below="@id/headerSpeedText"/>

        <!-- Et Cetera... -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I'd like to remark that this solution is by no means the best solution, but that it worked out fine for my proof-of-concept application!

Comment: Were you able to dispatch touch events relatively, if canvas is rotated to degree other than multiples of 180?
For ex: 50, 90, 270, 300?

Comment: Yes, any arbitrary rotation angle works. I was able to get readings from the phone's magnetometer, and to then use those readings to rotate the canvas so that the top of the mapView always showed the landmark that was directly in front of the user. Hope that makes sense!