# Rotational Pixel-Perfect Collision Detection

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

So I am working on an Android game and I have two images on the screen. I currently have the pixel-perfect collision detection working great. My problem is when I rotate one of the images and I check the pixels for a collision. The pixels are still oriented in the original way the image was loaded, so it is not as perfect as it was... I can get all of the pixels in an array, or a 2d array. But I am currently just accessing them by the `getPixel(x, y)` method in the `Bitmap` class.

Does anyone know of an algorithm to rotate the values in an array based on an arbitrary number of degrees? Or any other way of solving this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing pixels of the rotated image not the original one?

Comment: Well I was thinking about that, but when I load the bitmap at the beginning I am pretty sure that it stores the pixels once, but doesn't update them on rotation. I even tried to update them manually using the `getPixels()` and `setPixels()` methods on rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [`AffineTransform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html)?

It's what I have used to rotate sprites and images in the past.

Comment: I think that this will work. I just need to import java.awt to use it... which as I said in another comment is not supported on Android. I think I will search around on this idea and see if I can come up with a way to implement it.

Comment: You can use [`Matrix`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) instead of `AffineTransform`. See [How to map java's AffineTransform to Android's Matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534642/how-to-map-javas-affinetransform-to-androids-matrix) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code to rotate and get a pixel value from an image:

```
Image rotatedImage = new BufferedImage(imageToRotate.getHeight(null), imageToRotate.getWidth(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) rotatedImage.getGraphics();
// Set rotation here
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(90.0));
g2d.drawImage(imageToRotate, 0, -rotatedImage.getWidth(null), null);
g2d.dispose();
int pixelColor = ((BufferedImage)rotatedImage).getRGB(x, y);
```

Comment: This would require me to import the java.awt library because it is not supported on Android and I don't think I need this much overhead. I think Android's Bitmap class is the same as BufferedImage and I think the Graphics2D class is similar to the android Canvas. Hmm... I will look into this.