# Port CGAffineTransform from iOS to Android

Tags: android, ios

I have the next set of values:

```
0.439353, -0.073688, 0.078788, 0.439353, 139.500000, 72.000000
Let's name the values: a, b, c, d, tx, ty
```

On the iOS version of the app, these values are sent to this object ***[see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000946-CH2g-C016165)***

In my Android app I'm trying something like this:

```
Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
mtx.setValues(new float[] { a,  c, tx,  b,  d,  ty,  0,  0, 1});
```

Taken from ***[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534642/how-to-map-javas-affinetransform-to-androids-matrix)*** post, in Android the Matrix object accepts the values in that order (a,c,tx,b,d,ty) and not like the iOS version (a,b,c,d,tx,ty).

My problem is that the rotation and scaling are done correctly, but I'm having problems with the translation part. It does not position it correctly on the screen. Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I'm using the matrix to post a bitmap on a canvas, like so

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // .....
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, mtx, null);
}
```

Comment: I got the same issue, have you already figure it out?

Comment: unfortunately not, sorry.

Comment: I figure it out, see my answer. :)

Comment: i am taking matrix from image using getmatrix . which order should i follow ? i need to send the same matrix to IOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that iOS calculate the matrix based on the **center** position, but android and web are based on `{0,0}` position. So the solution is that you have to **move the bitmap to center position with correct scale relative to screen density first, then apply the matrix on**. My working well android code is:

```
Matrix matrixA = new Matrix();
matrixA.postTranslate(-bitmapWidth/2, -bitmapHeight/2);
matrixA.postScale(screenWidth/320, screenWidth/320);
Matrix matrixB = new Matrix();
matrixB.setValues(new float[]{scale, -rotate, tX, rotate, scale, tY, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F});
matrixA.postConcat(matrixB);

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrixA, null);
```

And the web css3 code is:

```
<img style="left: tX; top: tY; transform: matrix(scale, -rotate, rotate, scale, 0, 0) scale(window.screen.width/320);">
```

Comment: what the values(scale,rotate,tX and tY) are here at matrixB.setValues(new float[]{scale, -rotate, tX, rotate, scale, tY, 0.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F});

Comment: @user512 scale=a, rotate=b.

Comment: @Allen :  how we can set the same in ios? i am able to reproduce the matrix from ios to android . not able to reproduce in ios that are coming from ios .

Answer (score 4):

You can try to replace completely the matrix in canvas:

```
Canvas.save();
Canvas.setMatrix(mtx);
Canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, new Matrix(), null);
Canvas.restore();
```

Comment: The second parameter of drawBitmap method can not be set to null, or else the app crashes.

Comment: Then pass there just an identity matrix after you replaced matrix in canvas

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me get inspired, event though not correct .